# PostGIS ST_X() precision behaviour

Tags: postgresql, postgis, precision

We are investigating using PostGIS to perform some spacial filtering of data that has been gathered from a roving GPS engine.  We have defined some start and end points that we use in our  processing with the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tracksegments
(
   idtracksegments   bigserial   NOT NULL,
   name              text,
   approxstartpoint  geometry,
   approxendpoint    geometry,
   maxpoints         integer
);
```

If the data in this table is queried:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(approxstartpoint) FROM tracksegments
```

we get ...

```
POINT(-3.4525845 58.5133318)
```

Note that the Long/Lat points are given to 7 decimal places.

To get just the longitude element, we tried:

```
SELECT ST_X(approxstartpoint) AS long FROM tracksegments
```

we get ...

```
-3.45
```

We need much more precision than the 2 decimal places that are returned.  We've searched the documentation and there does not appear to be a way to set the level of precision.  Any help would be appreciated.

Vance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which PostgreSQL and PosGIS version are you using?

Comment: postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.5.21

Comment: select PostGIS_Lib_Version(); = 2.2.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. What do you get by firing `SELECT ST_X('POINT(-3.4525845 58.5133318)');` ?

Comment: btw, which postgres client are you using?

Comment: SELECT ST_X('POINT(-3.4525845 58.5133318)') = -3.45

Comment: That's odd. Which client are you using?

Comment: You've nailed it!  I'm using SQL Workbench (build 124).  When I use psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.21 from the command line I get:
    st_x    
------------
 -3.4525845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is definitely client related. Your client is most likely truncating `double precision` values for some reason. As [`ST_AsText`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) returns a `text` value, it does not get affected by this behaviour.

[`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) does not truncate the coordinate's precision like that, e.g.

```
SELECT ST_X('POINT(-3.4525845 58.5133318)');
    st_x    
------------
 -3.4525845
(1 Zeile)
```

Tested with `psql` in `PostgreSQL 9.5 + PostGIS 2.2` and `PostgreSQL 12.3 + PostGIS 3.0` and with pgAdmin III

[image]

**Note**: PostgreSQL 9.5 is a pretty old release! Besides the fact that it will reach EOL next January, you're missing really kickass features in the newer releases. I sincerely recommend you to plan a system upgrade as soon as possible.